# androidTest folder and apk not creating for product flavor android instrumentation testing

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, android-productflavors, android-instrumentation

I am facing a problem when testing the android instrumentation test using product flavor.
Here is details of my scenario:
My project `src` folder look:

[image]

Here `sp3` is my flavor. and `androidTes`t is the instrumentation test folder which contains `PresenterTest` class.

Here is my `gradle` flavor:

```
    flavorDimensions "main"

    // Product flavors
    productFlavors {
        //define sp3 configuration
        sp3 {
            dimension 'main'
            minSdkVersion deps.build.phone.minSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion deps.build.phone.targetSdkVersion
            applicationId "com.test.project"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "version_name"
        }
    }
```

When running the test its showing below error:

```
The APK file Project/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/sp3/debug/Project-sp3-debug-androidTest.apk does not exist on disk.
Error while Installing APK
```